# How to increment a byte array by one

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer, rocksdb

In RocksDB, we are able to perform range scan based on a key. We first seek to the start position by initializing byte[]. For example if your key is composed of two Long data types, we can initialize start byte[16] with `toBytes(Long.MinValue, Long.MinValue)`

Then set endKey by doing something similar `toBytes(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue)`. Note that we only want to scan last 64 bit from `Long.MinValue` to `Long.MaxValue` using this key as example to show we can scan byte[] partially.

Sample code can be found below. How does `iter.next()` work below? We are essentially incrementing byte[16] from start until we hit the end key. In other words, how do we increment byte[] by one? (or increment one bit at a time just like integer addition??) When checking the source code, it jumps to `native` function.

```
val iter = newRocksIterator()

new Iterator[Entry] {
  override def hasNext: Boolean = {
    if (iter.isValid) {

      if (compareKeys(iter.key(), endKey) > 0) false else true
    } else {
      false
    }
  }

  override def next(): Entry = {
    val value = Entry(iter.key, iter.value())
    iter.next()

    value
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what the KV pairs are and what kind of iteration you want

Comment: Could you post enough code for MRE? Take a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Wouldn't the database supply the next key in the range, since it _knows_ what the next key will be?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a transaction DB and do a read-modify-write cycle

or use the int64addition merge operator to do the increment at the key